# Error Running TypeORM Migration in NestJS: Unknown Arguments

Tags: nestjs-typeorm

## I'm encountering an issue while trying to run migrations using TypeORM within my NestJS application. Whenever I execute npm run migration:run, I receive the following error:

```
Usage: cli.js \<command\> \[options\]
...
Unknown arguments: =true, npm, run, typeorm
```

## I've configured my package.json with scripts for handling TypeORM migrations as follows:

```
{
  "name": "reward-service",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "author": "",
  "private": true,
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "nest build",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\" \"test/**/*.ts\"",
    "start": "nest start",
    "start:dev": "nest start --watch",
    "start:debug": "nest start --debug --watch",
    "start:prod": "node dist/main",
    "lint": "eslint \"{src,apps,libs,test}/**/*.ts\" --fix",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "test:cov": "jest --coverage",
    "test:debug": "node --inspect-brk -r tsconfig-paths/register -r ts-node/register node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand",
    "test:e2e": "jest --config ./test/jest-e2e.json",
    "typeorm": "ts-node ./node_modules/typeorm/cli",
    "migration:run": "typeorm=true npm run typeorm migration:run -- -d ./src/typeorm.ts",
    "migration:generate": "npm run typeorm -- -d ./src/typeorm.ts migration:generate ./migrations/$npm_config_name",
    "migration:create": "npm run typeorm -- migration:create ./migrations/$npm_config_name",
    "migration:revert": "npm run typeorm -- -d ./src/typeorm.ts migration:revert"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nestjs/common": "^10.0.0",
    "@nestjs/config": "^3.1.1",
    "@nestjs/core": "^10.0.0",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^10.0.0",
    "@nestjs/typeorm": "^10.0.0",
    "mysql2": "^3.6.2",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "rxjs": "^7.8.1",
    "typeorm": "^0.3.17"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nestjs/cli": "^10.0.0",
    "@nestjs/schematics": "^10.0.0",
    "@nestjs/testing": "^10.0.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.17",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.2",
    "@types/node": "^20.3.1",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.12",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.0.0",
    "eslint": "^8.42.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^5.0.0",
    "jest": "^29.5.0",
    "prettier": "^3.0.0",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.21",
    "supertest": "^6.3.3",
    "ts-jest": "^29.1.0",
    "ts-loader": "^9.4.3",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^4.2.0",
    "typescript": "^5.1.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "ts"
    ],
    "rootDir": "src",
    "testRegex": ".*\\.spec\\.ts$",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "**/*.(t|j)s"
    ],
    "coverageDirectory": "../coverage",
    "testEnvironment": "node"
  }
}
```

This is my typeorm.ts configuration file used for TypeORM setup:

```
import { registerAs } from '@nestjs/config';
import { config as dotenvConfig } from 'dotenv';
import { DataSource, DataSourceOptions } from 'typeorm';
import { Player } from './entities/Player';
import { Reward } from './entities/Reward';
import { Coupon } from './entities/Coupon';
import { PlayerCoupon } from './entities/PlayerCoupon';

dotenvConfig({ path: '.env' });

const config = {
  type: 'mysql',
  host: `${process.env.TYPEORM_HOST}`,
  port: `${process.env.TYPEORM_PORT}`,
  username: `${process.env.TYPEORM_USERNAME}`,
  password: `${process.env.TYPEORM_PASSWORD}`,
  database: `${process.env.TYPEORM_DATABASE}`,
  entities: [Player, Reward, Coupon, PlayerCoupon],
  migrations: process.env.typeorm === 'true' ? ['migrations/*.ts'] : [],
  autoLoadEntities: true,
  synchronize: false,
};

export default registerAs('typeorm', () => config);
export const connectionSource = new DataSource(config as DataSourceOptions);
```

## Additional Details:

Operating System: Windows 10
Node.js Version: node-v20.9.0-x64
NestJS Version: 10.2.1
TypeORM Version: 0.3.17

## Expected Outcome:

I expect the migration command (npm run migration:run) to execute without errors and run pending migrations for my NestJS application